# Segmentation Fault - Array out of bounds

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I wrote a simple algorithm so that when the user inputs an int N it'll create an N by N grid where there are no duplicates in the same row or column. The algorithm works sometimes with lower numbers, but often throws a segmentation fault. The fault happens in the noRowDuplicates function in the line where it sets an element of the grid array.

I'm not sure why this is happening and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

```
// Author: Eric Benjamin
// This problem was solved using recursion. fill() is the recursive function.


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void fillOptions();
void fill(int arrayPosition);
int inputNum;
int gridSize;
int *grid;
int allOptionsSize = 0;
int *allOptions;

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter a number!" << endl;
    cin >> inputNum;
    gridSize = inputNum * inputNum;

    grid = new int[gridSize];
    allOptions = new int[inputNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNum; i++) {
         allOptions[i] = i + 1;
         allOptionsSize++;
    }

    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    fill(0);

    delete[] grid;
    delete[] allOptions;
    return 0;
}

bool noColumnDuplicates(int arrPosition, int valueToCheck) {
    for (int i = 1; i < inputNum; i++) {
        if (arrPosition - (inputNum * i) >= 0) {
            if (grid[arrPosition - (inputNum * i)] == valueToCheck) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool noRowDuplicates(int arrPosition, int valueToCheck) {
    int rowPosition = arrPosition % inputNum; // 0 to num - 1
    if (rowPosition > 0) {
        for (int p = 1; p < rowPosition + 1; p++) {
            if (grid[arrPosition - p] == valueToCheck) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void fill(int arrayPosition) {
    if (arrayPosition < gridSize) {
        int randomPosition = rand() % allOptionsSize;
        grid[arrayPosition] = allOptions[randomPosition];
        if (noColumnDuplicates(arrayPosition, grid[arrayPosition])) {
            if (noRowDuplicates(arrayPosition, grid[arrayPosition])) {
                if (arrayPosition % inputNum == 0) {
                    cout << endl;
                }
                cout << grid[arrayPosition] << " ";
                fill(arrayPosition + 1);
            } else {
                fill (arrayPosition);
            }
        } else {
            fill(arrayPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Stop using C-style arrays in C++ and instead use `std::vector`.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` is considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces actually random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is [*barely* random at all](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Comment: Time to learn how to debug code

Comment: Get rid of all of the global variables.

Comment: It's not clear what `fill` does, you don't show the code, but I bet your problem is in there somewhere.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into and if you can stop now you might avoid a whole lot of headaches in the future. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason: It avoids conflict with your own classes, structures and variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial call to fill() will pass 0 for its parameter, `arrayPosition`.

`gridSize` is the size of your matrix/array.

If you examine the logic in your `fill()`, you will conclude that unless `arrayPosition` is equal to or greater than `gridSize`, a recursive call to `fill()` will be made, with `arrayPosition` either being the same, or incremented by 1.

All logical execution paths through `fill()`, when `arrayPosition < gridSize`, result in a recursive call to `fill()`.

In order words if, for example, your array/matrix has ten thousand values, your `fill()` will attempt to make at least (and likely many more than) ten thousand nested recursive calls to itself!

This is not going to end well. Your code encounters a segmentation fault when it blows through the maximum amount of stack space allotted to it, by your operating system, with your operating system refusing to allocate any more stack space to your process.

You will need to refactor your logic, to avoid this kind of out of control recursion. Unfortunately, stack space isn't infinite. The shown logic is fundamentally broken in C++. You cannot rely on your compiler eliminating tail recursion, and avoiding consuming stack space for every recursive function call.

A brief review suggests that nested recursion can be trivially replaced with a `while` loop. The overall algorithm would still have some room for improvement, but at least this will resolve the recursion issue.